# PHP insert and form validation issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple form which submits on a different page but it doesnt here, keep saying you need to enter name and email

I have echoed name and email variables but still the same

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['subs'])) {
        $name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']); 
        $email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        if (empty($name) || empty($email)) {
            echo"<div class='alert alert-danger'>Please enter both    name and email address</div>";}
        else {
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                echo"<div class='alert alert-danger'>Invalid email address, please enter a correct email address!</div>";
            }
            else {
                $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO subs (first_name, email) VALUES ('$name','$email')");
                if ($insert) {
                    echo"<div class='alert alert-success'>Thank you for subscribing wit us</div>";}
                }
            }
        }
?>

<div class="subs-mobile">
<form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control border-radius-zero" id="exampleInputPassword2"    placeholder="First Name" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control  border-radius-zero" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email" name="email">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary border-radius-zero" name="subs">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

Comment: did you get `Please enter both    name and email address` ?

Comment: yes i did, always coming up

Comment: `var_dump($name, $email);` - `false, false`?

Comment: both bool(false) bool(false)

Comment: isuue is mysql_real_escape_string but why?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['name'])` and `var_dump($_POST['name']) ` and change your form action to `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

Comment: @user3482036 you mean you can see the values if you place `var_dump($name, $email);` before the `mysql_real_escape_string` lines ? You are not echoing the path for the form action plus your html systax are incorrect.you have to add `</form>` at the bottom to wrap all the input elements and close the form tags.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are saying that your page submits at different page..but in the form action action field you are using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` which means your submitted data will be sent on the same page..you can either change the action field to the desired page or paste the script from other file to the script where form is made..
Second thing, at the beginning of the script in the isset function check whether `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['email']` are set or not..

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email']))
{

$name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']); 

 $email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

echo"<div class='alert alert-danger'>Invalid email address, please enter a correct email address!</div>";

else {

$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO subs (first_name, email) VALUES ('$name','$email')");

if ($insert) {echo"<div class='alert alert-success'>Thank you for subscribing wit us</div>";}
}
}

?>

    <body>
    <div class="subs-mobile">
       <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
      <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control border-radius-zero" id="exampleInputPassword2"    placeholder="First Name" name="name">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
   <input type="email" class="form-control  border-radius-zero" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email" name="email">
   </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary border-radius-zero" name="subs">Subscribe</button>
</form>
</body>
```

I hope now it will help you..and for more guide read this tutorial [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_required.asp)

Comment: done that now i can get both name and email but it doesnt insert $insert=mysql_query("INSERT into subs (first_name, email) VALUES ('$name','$email')");

Comment: @user3482036 make sure you are connected with your database and the field name provided in the query matches with the database columns..